# chrome adobe pdf reader javascript black screen

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, pdf

Hi there I generate a PDF document with our C# ASP.NET application.
We have a button that says "Generate PDF", then the following javascript code is called.

window.open("pdfdoc.pdf");

when I do that in Chrome, I get a blanco screen, when I hit CTRL+F5, sometimes the pdf is shown in the browser. weird or what?

if I run

document.location = "pdfdoc.pdf";

the pdf document shows up in the browser, but I want to open it in a new window.

I have the latest version of chrome (32.0.1700.76m) installed with the latest version of adobe acrobat reader plugin (11.0.06.70).

what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with your app but a problem with the Chrome version 32.XXX release. See this forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/uAWgIZZb01g/MtIzWG4casUJ  and this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333449